# sql query to get data for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have few columns in database for a table say choice which has option1-option15 columns.The data can be null in the column if the user has not selected it else it will 'y'.I need to just get those columns where data is 'y'.

```
column_id choice1 choic2 choice3......15

   1         null  y      null
   2         y     null   null
```

How can i get this using sql query for a given column id?

Comment: I don't have any idea for this,i am completely clueless so i posted here.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a database table in the opposite way to which they are designed.

You're trying to select fields (columns) from a table when data is present when you should be selecting data from fields based on some criteria. Also, what happens when you have another option added to your system? I assume you have to change the table design and all the procedures/applications using the table to recognise this new option.

It would be better to create a table containing the options as rows, then select all rows for a user. From your sample data (where each user has only one option selected) you would have two rows:

```
user_id option_number
------- -------------
      1             2
      2             1
```

If user 1 were to select more options, you add more rows:

```
user_id option_number
------- -------------
      1             2
      1             5
      1            10
      1            15
      2             1
```

The primary key of the table would be `(user_id, option_number)` to ensure a user could not select the same option twice. A relation to a lookup table (or a constraint) with all possible option numbers would prevent invalid options being selected.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what version of Oracle you are using. But you can query this data using an `UNPIVOT` or a `UNION ALL`:

`UNPIVOT` version (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93433/1)):

```
select *
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  val
  for col in (choice1, choice2, choice3)
) u
where val = 'y'
```

`UNION ALL` version (See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93433/3)):

```
select *
from
(
  select columnid, 'choice1' col, choice1 val
  from yourtable
  union all
  select columnid, 'choice2' col, choice2 val
  from yourtable
  union all
  select columnid, 'choice3' col, choice3 val
  from yourtable
) x
where val = 'y'
```

Doing this process, makes the data easily accessible in one column instead of over multiple columns.

Comment: the oracle version is 3.I am not able to run unpivot query what does 'col' specifies there ?and union All is not clear as per my requirement

Comment: @pars the `col` is just an alias for the column names, the `val` is the value that was under each of the columns.  If you cannot use `UNPIVOT` then a `UNION ALL` will also work.

Comment: @pars what do you mean not working?  do you get an error message?